# Assign value depending of value above in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got one dataframe df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'DF_1A' : ["A", 2, "B", 4, 5,6], 'DF_1B' : [10, 25, 40, 10, 15,12],'DF_3B' : np.nan})
```

[image]

I have to assign value to DF_3B if in DF_1A is number (the same row).
I there is A above then value is 100 and for B is 200.
After all the table should look like that:

[image]

EDIT:
So i try to explain it another way.
There will be loop through column DF_1A. Let each element of that loop will be x. Then:
- if x is a letter do nothing
- if x is numerical there are two possibilities
       a) if value of one row above x is letter then assign equivalent value of letter (100 or 200) in column DF_3B in the same row where is x
b) if value of one row above x is number then assign value DF_3B from one row above in column DF_3B in the same row where is x

Or maybe there is another easier way?

Thank you,
Jarek

Comment: please clarify "I there is A above then value is 100 and for B is 200. "

Comment: If there is A above number value in column DF_1A  then value (in the same row as number's row) in column DF_3B is 100 and for B is 200. Please look at output table to get the idea - columnd DF_3B.

Comment: Still not clear. Please could you explain: "I there is A above number value in column DF_1A then value in the same row as number's row in column DF_3B is 100 and for B is 200."

Comment: Seems like @Jarek means is if NOT(DF_1A[i].isdigit()) then NaN elseif DF_1A[i-1]=='A' & DF_1A[i].isdigit() then 100 else 200 i being the row index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to approach the problem. You didn't specify, how you store your substitution values, so I assumed a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'DF_1A' : ["A", 2, "B", 4, 5, 6, "A", 8, 9, 10], 'DF_1B' : [10, 25, 40, 10, 15, 12, 1, 3.7, 5, -2], 'DF_3B' : np.nan})

#transcription dictionary
transcr = {"A": 100, "B": 200}
#transfer values from row DF_1A to DF_3B, if they are in the dictionary
df1["DF_3B"] = df1.loc[df1["DF_1A"].isin(transcr), "DF_1A"]
#forward filling and substition of letters with values
df1["DF_3B"] = df1["DF_3B"].fillna(method='ffill').replace(transcr)
#resetting rows that contain letters to NaN
df1.loc[df1["DF_1A"].isin(transcr), "DF_3B"] = np.nan

print(df1)
```

Output

```
  DF_1A  DF_1B  DF_3B
0     A   10.0    NaN
1     2   25.0  100.0
2     B   40.0    NaN
3     4   10.0  200.0
4     5   15.0  200.0
5     6   12.0  200.0
6     A    1.0    NaN
7     8    3.7  100.0
8     9    5.0  100.0
9    10   -2.0  100.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought about using dictionary but have no idea how to implement it. That's better suits my needs. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but this would work:

`d1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'DF_1A' : ["A", 2, "B", 4, 5,6], 'DF_1B' : [10, 25, 40, 10, 15,12],'DF_3B' : np.nan})`

`d1['temp'] = np.where(d1['DF_1A'].shift(1)=='A',1,2)`

`d1['DF_3B'] = np.where(d1['DF_1A'].str.isdigit(),100,np.nan)*d1['temp']`

`d1.drop('temp',axis=1, inplace=True)`

`d1.head()`

Comment: Thank you for idea with shiftng! I think I cen use it to write some code:)

Comment: Sure, be careful when using shift and sort on the same dataset as shift operates on the index and sort does not implicitly reset the index.